# Obtener texto de un arreglo de JCheckBox al agregarle el ChangeListener dentro de un for

Tags: java, array

mi problema esta en que dentro del for donde inicializo mi arreglo de JChekBox le agrego el ChangeListener de paso, pero dentro de este no se como obtener el indice del JChexBox para obetener el texto que se encuentra en este. ejemplo:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < cbConvertirDe.length; x++){
        cbConvertirDe[x] = new JCheckBox(elementos[x]);
        cbConvertirDe[x].setBounds(264, posicionY, 200, 23);
        cbConvertirDe[x].addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                etiquetaNumero.setText("NUMERO "+cbConvertirDe[].getText()); //dentro de los corchetes no se que poner, no puedo utilizar la 'x' del for 
            }
        });
        panel.add(cbConvertirDe[x]);

        cbConvertirA[x] = new JCheckBox(elementos[x]);
        cbConvertirA[x].setBounds(466, posicionY, 200, 23);
        panel.add(cbConvertirA[x]);

        grupo1.add(cbConvertirDe[x]);
        grupo2.add(cbConvertirA[x]);
        posicionY += 23;
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que acabo de solucionar mi propia pregunta , la solución no era agregarle el ChangeLister en el mismo for de la inicialización, mas bien hice un método que lo mandaba a llamar después del for el cual era el siguiente: `

```
public void agregarChangeListener(){
        for(int i = 0; i < cbConvertirDe.length; i++){
            cbConvertirDe[i].addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    int indice = 0;
                    for(int x = 0; x < cbConvertirDe.length; x++){
                        if(cbConvertirDe[x].isSelected()){
                            indice = x;
                        }
                    }
                    etiquetaNumero.setText("NUMERO "+cbConvertirDe[indice].getText());
                }
            });

        }
    }`
```